# Can't get, the way how Height and Visibility works

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a sample application:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition /> <!-- Height="Auto" -->
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Some Header Text" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="switch" Content="Switch" IsChecked="True" />
      <ListView Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=switch, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
        <ListViewItem Content="11111111"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="22222222"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="33333333"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="44444444"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="55555555"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="66666666"/>
      </ListView>
      <ListView Grid.Row="2">
        <ListViewItem Content="aaaaaaaa"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="bbbbbbbb"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="cccccccc"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="dddddddd"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="eeeeeeee"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="ffffffff"/>
      </ListView>
    </Grid>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="Some Footer Text" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

BooleanToVisibilityConverter converts `true` to `Visible` and `false` to `Collapsed`.

If i execute the code as it is, then both list boxes are visible and they have the same height and scroll bars. So this is exactly, what i would expect. But, if i uncheck the check box, than the top list box disappears, but the row won't collapsed.

When i'd add `Height="Auto"` (on the line 15), then the behaviour of the top list box is as expected - it disappears and the second list box "goes" up. But when the check box is checked, then all controls are shown in their full size. The bottom of the second list box is outside of the window and there is no scroll bars and the footer is not visible any more (as it's outside of the window area).

My goal is to have both list boxes visible with scroll bars and let the top list box be collapsed by check box.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have second list and footer in the same grid's row?

Comment: No, there are two grids. The first one has three rows: header, inner grid and footer. The inner grid has three rows as well: check box, first list box and second list box. So, each control is placed in it's own row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is another factor in this situation: RowDefinition with `Height="*"` takes space even if there is no visible elements inside that Row (or even no elements at all). That is how Grid works.

introduce another panel: UniformGrid with 1 column. UniformGrid will give equal height to ListViews when both are visible, and give entire height to second ListView when first ListView is hidden.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="switch" Content="Switch" IsChecked="True" />
  <UniformGrid Columns="1" Grid.Row="1" >
   <ListView Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=switch, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
    <ListViewItem Content="11111111"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="22222222"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="33333333"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="44444444"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="55555555"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="66666666"/>
   </ListView>
   <ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="aaaaaaaa"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="bbbbbbbb"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="cccccccc"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="dddddddd"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="eeeeeeee"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="ffffffff"/>
   </ListView>
  </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

another alternative is to change second ListView Row and Rowspan when first ListView collapses:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="switch" Content="Switch" IsChecked="True" />
  <ListView Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=switch, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
    <ListViewItem Content="11111111"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="22222222"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="33333333"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="44444444"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="55555555"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="66666666"/>
  </ListView>
  <ListView>
    <ListView.Style>
     <Style TargetType="ListView">
      <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="2"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=switch}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
          <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="2"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
    <ListViewItem Content="aaaaaaaa"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="bbbbbbbb"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="cccccccc"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="dddddddd"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="eeeeeeee"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="ffffffff"/>
  </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is, that you can hide the `ListView`, but not the surrounding `GridRow`. So the `ListView` is collapsed, but not the Row, which still has its height set to `*`.

You can't easily hide `GridRows`. That is only possible by implementing it in code behind. I am not sure if you really want to do that. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/manipulate-columns-and-rows-by-using-columndefinitionscollections) would be an explanation on how to do this in code behind.

The easiest solution for you would be to use a different surrounding container. For example a `StackPanel` and set a `MaximumHeight` on your `ListViews` so not all elements are shown. Then the Visibility collapsed works as expected.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpfApp1="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApp1:BooleanConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <!-- Height="Auto" -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Some Header Text" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <CheckBox  x:Name="switch" Content="Switch" IsChecked="True" />
        <ListView  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=switch, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" MaxHeight="70">
            <ListViewItem Content="11111111"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="22222222"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="33333333"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="44444444"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="55555555"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="66666666"/>
        </ListView>
        <ListView  MaxHeight="70">
            <ListViewItem Content="aaaaaaaa"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="bbbbbbbb"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="cccccccc"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="dddddddd"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="eeeeeeee"/>
            <ListViewItem Content="ffffffff"/>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="Some Footer Text" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: You have defined `MaxHeight` for both ListBoxs. This is not the result I'd like to have. And if you'll remove `MaxHeight`, then StackPanel will have the size of the grid's row, but both lists will have their full size and the bottom of the second list will be outside of StackPanel and without scroll bar.

Comment: You should not put ScrollViewers inside StackPanels.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Style` that sets the `Height` of the `RowDefinition` to `0` when the `CheckBox` is unchecked. Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="*" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=switch}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RowDefinition.Style>
        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Some Header Text" />
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="switch" Content="Switch" IsChecked="True" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=switch, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
        <ListViewItem Content="11111111"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="22222222"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="33333333"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="44444444"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="55555555"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="66666666"/>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Grid.Row="3">
        <ListViewItem Content="aaaaaaaa"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="bbbbbbbb"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="cccccccc"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="dddddddd"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="eeeeeeee"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="ffffffff"/>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Text="Some Footer Text" />
</Grid>
```